# Https x509 client authentication not working when targetting UWP 14393 / .net standard 1.4

Tags: c#, azure, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have a lib A that targets .Net Standard 1.4 which makes `HttpClient.SendAsync` call:

`await Client.HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);`

`Client` is `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.ServiceClient` from 
microsoft.rest.clientruntime v2.3.11.

`Credentials` is `class X : ServiceClientCredentials` and the certificate is added in `InitializeServiceClient` using        `handler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certs);`

`ProcessHttpRequestAsync` is not overridden. 
The library is referenced from a stock standard UWP app.
The certificate used is added to MY certificate store. 
The test app is run on Windows Version 10.0.17134.

**Problem**

✔ When min version is 16299 the request is authorised correctly by the remote server.

✖ When min version is 14393 the request is **not** authorised i.e. the response is 401 Unauthorized.

**Question**

Is it possible to make a successful X509 client authentication https request targeting Windows 14393?

Comment: Which version of System.Net.Security and System.Net.Http does your library dependency on?Have you traced the log in the lib further?Hope this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9846) helps for you.